# how to use image cropper in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I have used image cropper in umbraco. I can see image on the content tab. Ihave saved and published. All I can see on the website is:

```
{
    "src": "/media/1023/stickyfooter.png",
    "focalPoint": {
        "left": 0.60666666666666669,
        "top": 0.32544378698224852
    },
    "crops": [{
        "alias": "fac",
        "width": 1000,
        "height": 500,
        "coordinates": null
    }]
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the raw data stored for image the image cropper, you need to use the getCropUrl() helper methods to get the particular URL for the image, rather than the raw data.  It should be something like

```
@Url.GetCropUrl(Model.Content, "yourImagePropertyName", "fac")
```

It's changed a bit over the years so the exact method could change depending on your version of Umbraco.  See https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/image-cropper#sample-code for more details.